# javascript issue

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

I have  adynamic grid, and the functionality of the data in there needs to work such that I can copy down data in my grid incrementally. Assuming in row 5, I enter 10, the following rows starting from the 6th row should read from 11 etc.

If I go to row one which is blank, and enter 2, the count should increment and auto-correct from that row 3 on where it should read next as 3.

My Issue: Unable to accomplish the above once I am on row 1 or 2 and increament from the number I started with on that row.

Any ideas for this?

Comment: Can you show us the code of any attempt you've made?

Comment: Interresting question, using a framework or plain old javascript? Adding the framework flag (ie. jQuery) will make it easier for people to awnser. Also wrote the grid code yourself or again, using a lib?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this easily by assigning change (onChange) event on each of the row. (You should use event delegation instead of assigning a separate event for each row)

For 1st and second row, you should treat the total so far as zero, so it will not break your code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate using some code? That would go along way of earning that rep and helping others since this answer isn't marked as accepted! :)